# How to set auto-increment field in postgresql different than id

Tags: java, postgresql, auto-increment

I have **id** column and **position** column in postgresql table. I want to position be auto-increment so I added **position** using **serial** data type:
`ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN position serial;`

```
id       name     position
-------  -------  -------
1        S4       4
2        S2       2
3        S3       3
4        S1       1
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to create new object I have following error:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "position" violates not-null`

What should I do to set **position** column auto-incremented?

My plain object:

```
public class Stg {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Integer position;
```

Comment: What is your version of Postgres?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 10.1

Comment: What's your INSERT statement?

Comment: Your alter statement alone should not be causing this error AFAIK.

Comment: @404 values which I put into statement looks like that (5, S5, null) so the position is obviously null however I do not have that problem with id - it is generated

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen should I use any annotation in my object?

Comment: @Bob if you specify NULL for the input of that column, you will get that error. You need to do something like `INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (5, 'S5');` - ignoring the `position` column, which will then get the default value from the sequence. I can't comment on how you do that from a java perspective, but that's how you'd do it in PG.

Comment: @404 I do not put value to *ID* field and it is generated correctly and here it looks like I put null

Comment: ID is irrelevant, the point is you can't set NULL for `position`, because defining it as SERIAL means it both gets a `NOT NULL` constraint and a default value of `NEXTVAL(your_sequence)`. If you supply `NULL` for that column's value, it will fail due to the constraint. So you either need to supply a value manually - in which case you shouldn't have defined it as SERIAL - or you don't specify that column at all in your INSERT, in which case it will automatically use the sequence to get an auto incrementing value.

Answer (score 0):

1st You need to create sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sys_sequence_name START -9223372036854775808 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807;
```

Then create table but after declaring row parameter add

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (

id          bigserial primary key,
var_with_seq    bigint not null default nextval('sys_sequence_name')
```

nextval('sys_sequence_name') - this will use the sequence You created.

Comment: Should I add some annotation to **position** field in **Stg** class?

Comment: You can add above private Integer position @SequenceGenerator(name="sys_sequence_name")

Comment: And ofc add @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="sys_sequence_name")

Comment: I tried before with this annotation but it doesn't work. Sequence in postgres works good but java still try to put null into position

Comment: hmm, try to add in Annotation @SequenceGenerator(name = "sys_seq_position_name", sequenceName = "sys_sequence_name",allocationSize = 1) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="sys_sequence_position_name") @Column(name="position", insertable=false) private Long position

Comment: I was looking at the same topic I guess - doesn't work for me. When I remove **position** field from class it works fine so aut-increment works well but java strill trying to put null into position.

Comment: Asking for Sure. You have @Entity and @Table(name="table_name_in_db") above class?

Comment: Don't know then, sry.